# I have this character idea but the magic is weird with it and I can't figure it out

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

I am very new to D&D 5e. The whole idea behind the character is that they can manipulate metal decently almost telekeneticaly, like throw a knife and control it in the air or tangle the bad guy up with some chains. Only issue is that I can't figure out how the magic system works nor can I figure out how to do this with a charcter. Is there something specific like an item to make this work or should I scrap the idea?

Comment: Are you trying to homebrew a class or are you asking if there is a way to do this with official classes?

Comment: And welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: I've voted to close your question since I think there are some details missing including wha NautArch mentioned: Does the character have to be a spellcaster? Are manipulating a knife to redirect to a different target and manipulating chains to tie up an enemy things your character absolutely needs to be able to do? Putting more constraints on what you need and want the character to be able to do will help a lot, though they may not all be possible. Also know that your question can always be reopened if you [edit] it so it fits the site's question-style/format better.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you asking about a psionic character?  In some previous editions, psionics was embedded into the rules but so far it's not "gone final" in this edition.

Comment: So you want to make Magneto as a playable class.  That's commendable and interesting.  This site is meant for answer specific questions.  The more specific the better.  If you have a brief set of examples that you need to figure out how to implement, it would make this a decent question.  I suggest asking about how to implement two specific features you'd like the class to be able to do. Having a good definition of what a feature needs to accomplish in order to be "working" would be useful as well.

Comment: Also, being very new to 5e, you will likely find it useful to play it as close to stock for a while to get a feel for the base mechanics before you decide to monkey around with homebrew material.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you're new to 5e and you're trying to do character creation.

The approach you've taken is you've decided on a character concept -- you want to build a character that can control metal -- and you want to build that as a 5e character.

My advice is that, as a first-time player, you'll probably have more fun if you choose one of the existing character classes and follow the standard rules for character creation.  Once you understand how the system is supposed to work, you can then experiment with new character concepts.

---

The best path to building a "character that can control metal" concept will probably be re-flavoring an existing class.  For example you might take the warlock character class, which normally deals damage using *eldritch blast*:

> A beam of crackling energy streaks toward a creature within range. Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 1d10 force damage.

and you'd re-flavor it as *telekinetic metal blast*:

> A cloud of metal scraps streaks toward a creature within range, flung by your telekinetic metal-controlling powers.  Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 1d10 force damage.

When your warlock got other spells and powers, you could reflavor those too if you wanted.

This doesn't change any game mechanics -- it only changes the narrative -- so your DM is more likely to be willing to let you create a character that does this.

Comment: Flavor/narration was how I was looking at this as well, but wanted to wait until OP had responded to my clarification request. Since you answered, you may want to address their specific requests for controlling a knife in the air or chains to tangle the bad guy up and/or other metal manipulation. I think this works really nicely with *eldritch blast*, but the larger request isn't quite there, especially since EB is only for creatures.

Comment: +1 for a great answer.
There's a longstanding myth that, "when playing a tabletop roleplaying game, you can make any character you can imagine." This is an exaggeration, at best: Each tabletop RPG is designed for specific settings, each setting has internal logic that limits what kinds of characters are possible in that setting, and each game has rules designed to support those kinds of characters. Re-flavouring existing rules *can* work, but has limits likely to prove frustrating; switching to a more appropriate character concept produces much more satisfying results.

Comment: @GMJoe you're not wrong, but there a lot of ways to have fun playing and we accept them all here.